# Can an array of database table column headings be created?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table `col-heading` whose columns are h1 to h40 and I want to store data in them by using an array of these column headings. Is it possible?

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO col_heading(h1---hn) VALUES ('$values')", $connection );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little unclear but to get all the column names from a particular table you can try something like this. You will note that it uses `mysqli` rather than the now deprecated `mysql` functions.

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'xxx';
$dbpwd = 'xxx';
$dbuser = 'xxx'; 

$db =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );


/* Get all columns from a particular table */
$sql="select `column_name` as 'column' 
        from `information_schema`.`columns` 
        where `table_schema`=database() and `table_name` = 'col_heading';";


$results=$db->query( $sql );
$columns=array();

while( $rs=$results->fetch_object() ){
    $columns[]=$rs->column;
}

$db->close();
$db=null;

echo '<pre>',print_r($columns),'</pre>';
```

Now you have an array of column names you should be able to use for the next operation.